# "Private" Rake tasks with the Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, rake

I know I can have the following to call a list of sub-tasks and have each one utilize the Rails environment of my project:

```
task :main_task => [:sub_task1, :sub_task2] do
end

task :sub_task1 => :environment do
  Model1.some_class_method
end

task :sub_task2 => :environment do
  Model2.some_class_method
end
```

My questions are

1. Is there any way in `:main_task` to pass the `:environment` so that I don't have to explicitly put it in each sub-task?
2. Is there any way to make the sub-tasks be considered "private"?  That is, I don't want them to be explicitly called individually.  They would only ever execute from `:main_task`.  Basically I need to read data out of one database (SQLServer) and populate another (MySQL - the Rails project's db), but I want to keep the "read" task separate from the "populate" task for good readability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can list the `:environment` task once in the parent task before the other two to have it listed only once.

```
task :main_task => [:environment, :sub_task1, :sub_task2] do
end
```

There are no "private" tasks, however you can keep them from being listed by `rake -T` by not putting a `desc` line above them. You could enforce them manually by throwing an exception if they are called directly (detecting something the parent does, or some such).

However, you would probably have a better time putting the code in a shared method or class which is not directly exposed as a rake task.